# Empty result when asking for auto-generated channel's live events

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm having troubles fetching live videos from channels auto-generated by YouTube, e.g. [this one](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4QHogDHk5p-GZoB4DCfJXw).

[Try it example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=en&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22UC4QHogDHk5p-GZoB4DCfJXw%22%2C%22eventType%22%3A%22live%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A25%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22video%22%5D%7D) in YouTube Data API manual. When no channel or an actual user-made channelId is specified, proper results are returned.

Comment: I confirm reproducing your issue. I'd recommend to file a bug report to Google through its own [issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Interesting is the following fact: querying the `Channel.list` endpoint for this channel's `statistics` property (on the URL `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=UC4QHogDHk5p-GZoB4DCfJXw&part=statistics&fields=items/statistics&key=...`), the following JSON is obtained `{"items":[{"statistics":{"viewCount":"0","subscriberCount":"12700","hiddenSubscriberCount":false,"videoCount":"0"}}]}`.

Comment: This shows this channel's `viewCount` and `videoCount` to be zero! Yet the YouTube site displays quite a lot of videos under the tabs [Recent](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4QHogDHk5p-GZoB4DCfJXw/recent), [Explore](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4QHogDHk5p-GZoB4DCfJXw/explore) and [Official](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4QHogDHk5p-GZoB4DCfJXw/official).